# How to change shortcut keys for a given command in ReSharper?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, resharper

I need to change shortcut for finding member (<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>) in ReSharper because of my native keyboard which brings me problem to press wrong key each time.

Where can I re-set a new key combination for shortcuts in ReSharper?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use Visual Studio's Keyboard options pane to change keyboard shortcut bindings.  This can be found in Visual Studio by going *Tools* > *Options* > *Environment* > *Keyboard*.