# Resharper Shortcut Keys in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

i want to when i press ctrl+; "Semicolon key" resharper's "Complete Statement"s command be executed.
any other idea for intelligent and easy to use line completation exists?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change shortcut keys for a given command in ReSharper?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657579/how-to-change-shortcut-keys-for-a-given-command-in-resharper)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Visual Studio select 
Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard

which brings up the dialog as shown below. Filter by 'complete'[image]

Select 'Resharper.Resharper_CompleteStatement, enter your shortcut key, then press Assign and you are done.